# How put form field value into "url" of getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<span id="results"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txt').change(function(){
        var miasto = $("#txt").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality:" + miasto + "|country:PL&key=AIzaSyB0Yn_8C4os4dRBhEs1nSVXx1TbmolDl3k&sensor=false",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                var zcity = $("#txt").val();
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#results').html('<br />City: ' + json.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + '<br />Kraj: ' + json.results[0].address_components[4].short_name + '<br /> Input Value: ' + zcity);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

With this code I need entered value of INPUT, put into a URL value of "$.ajax" section.
What did I do wrong? When I remove line

```
var miasto = $("#txt").val();
```

and instead + miasto + enter a single word (ex. Warszawa), all works fine and the change event of input #txt print the results of Ajax call

How put entered value to input into "url:" value in jQuery code?

Comment: Do a `console.log(miasto)` before ajax call and send us the output.

Comment: It works [in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj6f7ary/) "as is".

Comment: Console output:

 - TypeError: json.results[0] is undefined

@Regent : in that case, the entered value into INPUT was printed after all when all is fine... is not printed when i try put var miasto into URL

Comment: problem is your ajax call return zero result : `{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}`

Comment: @X9DESIGN I can't understand what the problem is about. I typed "Warszawa" in `input` and code works just fine. With this `var miasto = $("#txt").val();` in the code.

Comment: @X9DESIGN if you type a city of `PL` country (for example `Warszawa`) results show correctly. you must check zero result before fill html  to prevent from errors !

Comment: Sorry... all is correct now! This is my falut.. i just forgot just simple thing :) i Must eneter Ful name of City, not only part ... sorry .. Thank You all

Comment: @X9DESIGN I recommend to add checking for json result to prevent from Zero result error .

Comment: @X9DESIGN look at this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldwdy49w/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You must enter city name located in `PL` country only
so I recommend to add json result checking to prevent from Zero result error .

of course you can enter some unique part of city name for example `"warsaz"` for `"Warszawa"` or `"biaystk"` for `"Bialystok"`

```
$('#results').html('no result');    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#txt').change(function(){
                var miasto = $("#txt").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality:" + miasto + "|country:PL&key=AIzaSyB0Yn_8C4os4dRBhEs1nSVXx1TbmolDl3k&sensor=false",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var zcity = $("#txt").val();
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (json.status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                            $('#results').html('<br />City: ' + json.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + '<br />Kraj: ' + json.results[0].address_components[4].short_name + '<br /> Input Value: ' + zcity);
                        } else { 
                            $('#results').html('Invalid City name for PL Country');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldwdy49w/2/)